# How can I grab a selection of markers with Leaflet.draw?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

**Context:**

I've made a map, and populated it with around 300 random markers. I can 'select' the markers by clicking on a link in the popup and activate a selection to display data from. I also have the Leaflet.draw plugin to draw shapes like circles, rectangles and custom shapes, and I would like to use it to 'select' a couple of markers.

**The issue**

How can I grab the leaflet marker object of the markers that fall inside a drawn leaflet.draw shape so I can edit them? I cannot seem to make a selection, It either selects none of the markers, or all of them.

Code snippet, stripped from unnecessary code:

```
const drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        marker   : false,
        polygon  : true,
        polyline : false,
        rectangle: true,
        circle   : {
            metric: 'metric'
        }
    },
    edit: false
});

const map = L.map('map', {
    layers: [streets, light]
}).setView([CONFIG.MAP.LATITUDE, CONFIG.MAP.LONGITUDE], CONFIG.MAP.ZOOMLEVEL)

map.addControl(drawControl);

map.on(L.Draw.Event.DRAWSTOP, e => {

    const hello = e.target;

    console.log(hello);
    e.target.eachLayer(layer => {
        if (layer.options.icon) {
            console.log(layer);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most of what you want can quite easily be done using Leaflet's utility methods. If you want to do this with a complex shape like `L.Polygon` you're going to need something like [TurfJS](http://turfjs.org/)

For `L.Circle` you need to calculate the distance between the circle's center and compare it to the radius:

```
var marker = new L.Marker(...),
    circle = new L.Circle(...);

var contains = circle.getLatLng().distanceTo(marker.getLatLng()) < circle.getRadius();
```

For `L.Rectangle` you need to fetch it's bounds object and use the contains method:

```
var marker = new L.Marker(...),
    rectangle = new L.Rectangle(...);

var contains = rectangle.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng());
```

As said for complex polygons i'de use Turf but there are more libraries and plugins out there. Here's an example using Turf's `inside` method. It take a GeoJSON point and polygon feature as parameters so mind the conversion:

```
var marker = new L.Marker(...),
    polygon = new L.Polygon(...);

var contains = turf.inside(marker.toGeoJSON(), polygon.toGeoJSON());
```

You could wrap those into convenience methods for each respective class:

```
L.Polygon.include({
    contains: function (latLng) {
        return turf.inside(new L.Marker(latLng).toGeoJSON(), this.toGeoJSON());
    } 
});

L.Rectangle.include({
    contains: function (latLng) {
        return this.getBounds().contains(latLng);
    }
});

L.Circle.include({
    contains: function (latLng) {
        return this.getLatLng().distanceTo(latLng) < this.getRadius();
    }
});

var marker = new L.Marker(...),
    polygon = new L.Polygon(...),
    rectangle = new L.Rectangle(...),
    circle = new L.Circle(...);

polygon.contains(marker.getLatLng());
rectangle.contains(marker.getLatLng());
circle.contains(marker.getLatLng());
```

Note that if you implement the polygon method that there is no need for the rectangle method. Since rectangle is extended from polygon it will inherit the method. I left it in there to be complete.

Now iterating your markers and comparing them is easy:

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    markers.eachLayer(function (marker) {
        if (!e.layer.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Hope that helps, here's a working snippet:

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0
});

var markers = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
    var marker = new L.Marker([
        (Math.random() * (90 - -90) + -90).toFixed(5) * 1,
        (Math.random() * (180 - -180) + -180).toFixed(5) * 1
    ]).addTo(markers);
}

new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        marker   : false,
        polygon  : true,
        polyline : false,
        rectangle: true,
        circle   : {
            metric: 'metric'
        }
    },
    edit: false
}).addTo(map);

L.Polygon.include({
    contains: function (latLng) {
        return turf.inside(new L.Marker(latLng).toGeoJSON(), this.toGeoJSON());
    } 
});

L.Rectangle.include({
    contains: function (latLng) {
        return this.getBounds().contains(latLng);
    }
});

L.Circle.include({
    contains: function (latLng) {
        return this.getLatLng().distanceTo(latLng) < this.getRadius();
    }
});

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    markers.eachLayer(function (marker) {
        if (!e.layer.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
            marker.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 1.0.3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.9/leaflet.draw.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.9/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/@turf/turf@latest/turf.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Holy bananas, i've been looking through this all morning, let me try and converting it to my own codebase, massive thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Works fantastic, thank you very, very much for your help :).

Comment: Absolutely no problem, no need to thank, always welcome.That's what we're here for ;)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @iH8 for the cool example. I went further to avoid some repetition with

```
markers.eachLayer(function (marker) {
    ...
}
```

and extended the wrappers with additionnal methods using arrays of markers instead:

---

First I noticed that a `LayerGroup` has an object with key-values containing all the markers. I simply use that object to create an array of markers :

```
// In the on draw event
...
// Set an array containing all the markers
var markers = jsonToArray(layerGroup._layers); 
...

function jsonToArray(jsonObject) {
  var result = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);
  keys.forEach(function (key) {
    result.push(jsonObject[key]);
  });
  return result;
}
```

I then re-use the wrappers with modified `contains()` methods :

```
  L.Rectangle.include({
    // Single marker case
    contains: function (marker) {
      return this.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng());
    },
    // Array of markers
    contains: function (markers) {
      var markersContained = [];
      markers.forEach(marker => {
        markersContained.push(this.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng()));
      })
      return markersContained;
    }
  });

  L.Circle.include({
    contains: function (marker) {
      return this.getLatLng().distanceTo(marker.getLatLng()) < this.getRadius();
    },
    contains: function (markers) {
      var markersContained = [];
      markers.forEach(marker => {
        markersContained.push(this.getLatLng().distanceTo(marker.getLatLng()) < this.getRadius());
      })
      return markersContained;
    }
  });
```

and finally on the draw event, I check whether my markers are contained within or not :

```
  map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (geometry) {
    // Set an array containing all the markers
    var markers = jsonToArray(layerGroup._layers);

    var result = geometry.layer.contains(markers);
    console.log('result => ', result);
  });
```

```js
function jsonToArray(jsonObject) {
  var result = [];
  var keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);
  keys.forEach(function (key) {
    result.push(jsonObject[key]);
  });
  return result;
}

var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    'center': [0, 0],
    'zoom': 0
});

var layerGroup = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var marker = new L.Marker([
        (Math.random() * (90 - -90) + -90).toFixed(5) * 1,
        (Math.random() * (180 - -180) + -180).toFixed(5) * 1
    ]).addTo(layerGroup);
}

new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        marker   : false,
        polygon  : false,
        polyline : false,
        rectangle: true,
        circle   : {
            metric: 'metric'
        }
    },
    edit: false
}).addTo(map);

// Define contains() method for each geometry
L.Rectangle.include({
  contains: function (marker) {
    return this.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng());
  },
  contains: function (markers) {
    var markersContained = [];
    markers.forEach(marker => {
      markersContained.push(this.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng()));
    })
    return markersContained;
  }
});

L.Circle.include({
  contains: function (marker) {
    return this.getLatLng().distanceTo(marker.getLatLng()) < this.getRadius();
  },
  contains: function (markers) {
    var markersContained = [];
    markers.forEach(marker => {
      markersContained.push(this.getLatLng().distanceTo(marker.getLatLng()) < this.getRadius());
    })
    return markersContained;
  }
});

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (geometry) {
  // Set an array containing all the markers
  var markers = jsonToArray(layerGroup._layers);

  var result = geometry.layer.contains(markers);
  console.log('result => ', result);
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 1.0.3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.9/leaflet.draw.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.9/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you! Can you suggest a way for me to console.log the marker contents rather than true / false? Ideally I'd like to select a group of pins on the map and return some sort of pin ID.

Comment: I haven't worked on this project for a long time, but I guess you could try logging the marker itself ? 
Honestly, I don't really know anymore

Comment: I ended up sorting this out, in case it's helpful to anyone I've included my code here. This returns the marker data rather than True and False :   L.Rectangle.include({
    contains: function (markers) {
      var markersContained = markers.filter(marker => {
        return this.getBounds().contains(marker.getLatLng()) === true;
      })
      return markersContained;
    }
  });

Answer (score 0):

I used it：

```
L.Circle.include({
    contains: function (latLng) {
        return this.getLatLng().distanceTo(latLng) < this.getRadius();
    }
});
```

Points that are on the edge but not in the circle are also judged.