# Get markers within bounds

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer, leaflet.draw

I'm using the **last version** of Leaflet and MarkerCluster.

[image]

After I draw a polygon on the map, I'd like to select all markers within it. I know the bounds of the polygon. Also, I know the coordinates of the markers.

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {
    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

   for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

   }

    editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261122/how-can-i-grab-a-selection-of-markers-with-leaflet-draw/